# Using Join Tables to Save Info Selected from Drop-down Menus

Tags: php, mysql, sql, drop-down-menu

I'm learning PHP and MySQL from books and online resources. As a learn-as-I-go project I've been creating a web site that will allow me to catalog my movie collection. I've created a database, and have a series of tables set up to hold the necessary information.

I'm building a page that will allow me to input the data for a movie. I've hit a roadblock when it comes to using the "join tables". I can't find any information to help me, and I hope someone here can help.

I can create a drop-down list of all the records in a given table, but I don't know how to take whatever the user chooses from that drop-down list and work with it. What I want to do is give two drop-down lists, and let the user choose one item from list A, and as many items as needed from list B, and then save all that info into the various tables.

In more specific detail:

I have 4 tables:

```
movie_info (movie_id, movie_title, movie_year, genre_id)

movie_genres (movie_genre_id, movie_genre_name)

movie_directors (movie_director_id, movie_director_name)

movies_directors_join (movies_directors_join_id, movie_id, movie_director_id)
```

On the create movie web page I want to present a field into which the user can type in the movie name, and another in which to type the year. I can do that.

I want to present a drop-down list of the different genres, which I can create using a function I wrote:

```
function query_genre () {
    $myData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM movie_genres ORDER BY movie_genre_name ASC");
    while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
        echo '<option value = ' . $record['movie_genre_id'] . '>' .
        $record['movie_genre_name'] . ' </option>';
    }
}
```

And then calling it:

```
<p>Choose a Genre
     <select name="dropdown">
         <?php query_genre() ?>
     </select>
</p>
```

I want the user to choose one genre, and have the genre_id of the chosen genre become the genre_id in the movie_info table. I can't do that.

I want a drop-down list of the different directors, which I can create using a function similar to the one above.

A movie can have more than one director, so I want some way the user can select a director from the drop-down and "add" him to the film info. If need be, the user can select another director, and add him as well, until all directors are listed.

Once the title, year, genre, and director(s) are all in place, the user can click "submit" and a record will be added to movie_info, and a record (or records) will be added to movies_directors_join.

Comment: what is the result you get?

Comment: I don't get a result because I don't know how to do it. That's what I'm asking-- how do I go from simply presenting a dropdown list to letting a user select an item from it and add it to the details about the film?

Answer (score 0):

Using following code you can create first drop down.

```
  <?php
    $sql_manager ="SELECT * FROM movie_genres ORDER BY movie_genre_name ASC";
    $rslt_manager = $obj -> select($sql_manager); //$obj is object of db class.(create   one)
    ?>

     <select name="movie">
        <option value=''>===Select===</option>
              <?
                 for($mg=0;$mg<count($rslt_manager);$mg++)
                   {
               ?>
                   <option value="<?=$rslt_manager[$mg]['movie_genre_id'];?>"><? echo $rslt_manager[$mg]['movie_genre_name'];?></option>
                <?
                    }

                 ?>
         </select>
```

For second drop down of Multiple selection, you can use jquery `multipleselect` plugin which will give you checkboxes to select multiple values.

Comment: Thank you for offering that. I trust it will work, but how it works is beyond my scope. I've worked through 3 books on PHP and MySQL, but don't understand nearly anything I see here. Can you recommend a book or webpage or video that can teach me the core concepts behind what you've done there?

Comment: It is simple concatenations only. You can use w3school website for basic concepts.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out how to do it in a much easier way than suggested above. I only had to add " multiple" and "[]" and it worked. No need for any jquery or whatever arcane advanced stuff was suggested above. Yay!

Here is what worked:

```
<select name="dropdown_director[]" multiple>
                    <?php query_director() ?>
                </select>
```